# FTIR data: Is there a way to obtain stat significant differences observed between groups in LD-PCA?

Tags: computational-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, chemometrics

Besides checking the loadings and choosing peaks of interest, there is a way to point out from the LD-PCA or PCA the differences between groups that are significant?

All ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: For ease of access (subscribers of the page of all levels of study) as well as to attract future interested into the topic (newly submitted tag `chemometrics`) I suggest you either explain once the abbreviations used, or link them to an accessible reference.